# Окрашенный текст перенести в Google Docs

Tags: c#

Я хочу, код который я пишу на C# в VS22, вставить в Google Docs в такой же раскраске синтаксиса как он идёт в дефолтном VS22.

Как это можно сделать ?

1. Если просто из VS22 скопировать код и вставить в Google Docs, вставляется он ч/б.
2. Я думал использовать RichTextBox у WinForms или WPF, частично текст раскрашивается если вставить копипастом из VS22 в RichTextBox, но копипастом из RichTextBox в Google Docs он вставляйся ч/б.
   Пробовал так же из RichTextBox в буфер получать программно в различных форматах для вставки в Google Docs, но без успехов.

Comment: Исследуйте буфер обмена. Смотрите, какие там форматы копируются и есть ли где-то цвета. Далее преобразуйте цветной текст в HTML и перезапишите буфер.

Comment: Кстати, есть готовое расширение https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TimMathias.CopyAsHtml2022

Comment: @aepot как всегда, спасибо!

Comment: @aepot это расширение в micrisoft word - html - преобразует в сode snippet, но стили отвратные и многое не окрашено, а вот в google docs как текст просто вставляет. не преобразует html.

Comment: стоит к слову упомняуть, что в visual studio есть настройка длины текста выходя за которую текст копируется форматирования (без цветов)